# Can a disk clone be recognized?

Tags: disk-cloning

When you clone a disk, is there a way to distinguish the clone from the original, such as a timestamp or any other information that could be read from both disks and compared ?

Comment: @Akina: Please post a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The difference (if exists) is outside of data.

Assuming that "clone" is sector-by-sector copying, of course.

If source and destination differs at least in one bit - it is wrong/damaged clone.

Comment: The title and the body of my question expect inverse answers (I am fixing that), can I assume that you answer the body ?

Comment: @HarryCover Yes.